# Unity3d Gyroscope only for Z axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, gyroscope

I'm trying to figure out how Gyroscope works on iOS and Android and I went through this tutorial: http://blog.heyworks.com/how-to-write-gyroscope-controller-with-unity3d/

What I would like to know, is how do I need to modify the sourcecode (there's a downloadlink on that page), so that it reads only from the phone's z-axis? I have already played around with it and created a new Quaternion object like this:

```
Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Euler(initialRotation.eulerAngles.x, initialRotation.eulerAngles.y, gyroRotation.eulerAngles.z);
transform.rotation = newRotation;
```

it seemed to work, but then I noticed, when I rotate the phone around it's y-axis (let's say 20 degrees) and THEN start to tilt it in x-direction, it reacts like it would be rotated in z-direction (just slower).

What I would like to do is the following:
I want to have an object placed in the middle of the screen with an initial rotation of 0. When the phone gets rotated around it's z-axis, I want the object to rotate against the phone's rotation, so that it looks like the object keeps it's rotation regardless of how the phone is rotated around z.

Comment: Have you got any solution for that? I am getting in the same problem, if you debugged, you will see that the values are changing from the sensor it self. They need to be somehow corrected.